# Sharepoint Server Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, runtime

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

I am getting this error in every site running SharePoint, even central administration. I located `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` and changed web config file to Custom Errors= Off in each of the servers but the problem persists. I also checked the SQL if any of the databases were corrupted, but in fact they were running properly. All my application pools are started. I tried `iisreset` but, the outcome was the same. [image: Here is the full error]

Comment: Have you modified any thing masterpage? Do you have webparts?

Comment: No, i have not used any custom web part. Nothing was modified, I left it over the weekend working properly and when I came back I had this error

Comment: Try adding Custom Errors= Off in your web.config in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<Port> Also

Comment: Check the Event Viewer on your CentralAdmin Server.

Comment: Ran into this today and it was because of insufficient SQL permissions. Check your SQL permissions and make sure teh farm account has access to the config and admincontent databases.

Comment: I think I found where the problem is. One of my databases (config) is recovery pending status. Any idea how can I solve it ?